# How do I equip the DLC outfits?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

I have the Sonic Frontiers DLC for the [Sonic Adventure 2 Shoes](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2089840/Sonic_Frontiers_Sonic_Adventure_2_Shoes/), [Monster Hunter Collaboration Pack](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2089730/Sonic_Frontiers_Monster_Hunter_Collaboration_Pack/), and [Holiday Cheer Suit](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2089733/Sonic_Frontiers_Holiday_Cheer_Suit/). How do I equip the cosmetic outfits from the DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Main menu of the game, ***before*** loading a save slot, go to the [Extras] section. Here you can equip DLC cosmetics.

[image]